# Call SipJs to Asterisk 12

Tags: sip, asterisk, webrtc

I trying to call from SIpJs to Asterisk 12. my peer is here

```
[6002]
type=friend
secret=6002
host=dynamic
context=public
transport=ws
avpf=yes
icesupport=no
encryption = no
```

and my JsSip code is here

```
  var configuration = {
            'ws_servers': 'ws://192.168.0.102:8088/ws',
            'uri': 'sip:6002@192.168.0.102',
            'password': '6002'
        };
var options = {
            'eventHandlers': eventHandlers,
            'mediaConstraints': {'audio': true, 'video': false}
        };

        function call() {
            coolPhone.call('sip:6003@192.168.0.102', options);
        }
```

It is register corretly , but when i call "call" function asterisk logs this error

```
 Rejecting secure audio stream without encryption details: audio 46421 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126
```

JSSIp error is here

call failed with cause: Incompatible SDP

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `encryption = yes` and try again..remember to reload sip configuration

Comment: Thank you for reply, but result is same

Comment: well, make sure that your RTC sip client is properly configured like [here](http://sipjs.com/guides/server-configuration/asterisk/)

Comment: I nan not understan one moment, need I sny sertificates? i am not use wss, i use ws

Comment: You need certificate (it may be self signed) for DTLS, not for WSS. You can go on with WS. Follow literally the steps of the tutorial that AlexGreg has mentioned in his comment above.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create certificates for DTLS. Then enable DTLS from each of your peers.

Use the below command for creating certificates.(Replace X.X.X.X with your asterisk server IP)

```
mkdir /etc/asterisk/keys
cd ${ASTERISKSOURCE_PATH}/contrib/scripts/
./ast_tls_cert -C X.X.X.X -O "My Super Company" -d /etc/asterisk/keys
```

Then add the below keys with your peer:

```
dtlsenable=yes ; Tell Asterisk to enable DTLS for this peer
dtlsverify=no ; Tell Asterisk to not verify your DTLS certs
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem ; Tell Asterisk where your DTLS cert file is
dtlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem ; Tell Asterisk where your DTLS private key is
dtlssetup=actpass ; Tell Asterisk to use actpass SDP parameter when setting up DTLS
```